# Make links have the same distance

Tags: html, hyperlink, distance

I am trying to make a simple website and I need some help.

I have this div

```
<div id="header">
<?php require "./Pages/header.html"; ?>
</div>
```

And the header html:

```
<a href="index.php?p=home">Home</a>
<a href="index.php?p=shopinfo">Shop Information</a>
<a href="index.php?p=products">Products</a>
<a href="index.php?p=cart">Cart</a>
<a href="index.php?p=login">Login</a>
<a href="index.php?p=contact">Contact</a>
```

I want something like this:

Home       Shop Information             Products             Cart               Login                    Contact

where Home will be at the beggining of the div and Contact will be at the end of the div and all these links will have the same distance, but I dont want to use `&nbsp;` spaces.

Comment: By same distance, do you mean equal width?

Comment: Use an invisible table

Comment: @Chitowns24 using table for formatting is deprecated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `ul`

```
  <ul>
     <li><a href="index.php?p=home">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="index.php?p=shopinfo">Shop Information</a></li>
     <li><a href="index.php?p=products">Products</a></li>
     <li><a href="index.php?p=cart">Cart</a></li>
     <li><a href="index.php?p=contact">Contact</a></li> 
 </ul>
```

CSS

```
 ul li
 {
     display:inline;
     padding:5px;
 }
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4PkHy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of options. You can use margin-right or padding.
JS-fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Uq9y/

```
<a href="index.php?p=home">Home</a>
<a href="index.php?p=shopinfo">Shop Information</a>
<a href="index.php?p=products">Products</a>
<a href="index.php?p=cart">Cart</a>
<a href="index.php?p=login">Login</a>
<a href="index.php?p=contact">Contact</a>
```

css:

```
a{
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `<nav>` tag

```
<nav>

<a href="index.php?p=home">Home</a>
<a href="index.php?p=shopinfo">Shop Information</a>
<a href="index.php?p=products">Products</a>
<a href="index.php?p=cart">Cart</a>
<a href="index.php?p=login">Login</a>
<a href="index.php?p=contact">Contact</a>

</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav { 
      display:block; 
      margin-left:auto;
      margin-right:auto; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Using your existing html/php code :

```
div#header a {
    margin-right: 10px; 
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
<title>Test Website</title>
<style>
#menubar{
    position: relative;
    margin: 25px auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 900px;
    height: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: #ffffff;
    border-left: 2px solid #010000;
    border-right: 2px solid #010000;
}
#menubar ul {
    margin-top:15px;
}
#menubar ul li{
     display: inline;
    margin: 25px 10px 15px 15px;
    padding: 25px;
}

#menubar ul li a{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#menubar ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="menubar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php?p=home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?p=shopinfo">Shop Information</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?p=products">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?p=cart">Cart</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?p=login">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.php?p=contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]